# CakePHP 2.1: Using CSRF protection on Elements

Tags: security, cakephp, csrf, cakephp-2.1

I have a somewhat special situation with one of my CommentsController actions, the "add" action.
Since I have an "Add Comment" form on my "view" View of PostsController, I have an "add_comment" Element instead of an "add" View for the Comments. This is that I can just insert the Element with the form inside the "view" View of Posts. I hope this does not sound too complicated.

Now, inside the "add_comment" Element, the form gets submitted to the actual "add" action of CommentsController. If the form has to be rendered again, because of invalid user input for exaxmple, the form gets rendered again by - this time - calling the "add" View of Comments. This "add" View only again includes the "add_comment" Element, which - as was said above - includes the actual form.

Now the thing is, I added the Security component to my CommentsController in order to get CSRF protection. All my admin actions of CommentsController get the protection i.e. e token is rendered inside the form and checked upon submitting the form.

Still, the add_comments Element form does NOT get a token. Probably because it is an Element and not the corresponding View.

How can I manually insert a token into the Element's form or how do I better solve this?

Thank you

**EDIT:** Se also [my other question regarding the setup - it should explain it a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347098/cakephp-2-1-validating-forms-coming-from-elements-in-a-smooth-way?rq=1)

**EDIT2:** [This](http://pastebin.com/GNESQF9U) is what's inside my add_comment Element

**EDIT3:** [This](http://pastebin.com/wgnn5jKz) is the HTML output of the add_comment element. The nonce should be in the `<div style="display:none;">` part.

**EDIT4:** I put `Debugger::log($this->Form->request->params);` inside the element (add_comment.ctp) and the view (add.ctp) and [this](http://pastebin.com/bXPESsMX) shows the output.

I also uploaded the the whole CommentsController ([here](http://pastebin.com/4HPcHu6a)). Please note that I specified a blackhole function to catch errors of type 'auth'. This is because, every time I entered invalid data in the add_comments.ctp Element and - by submitting the form - the actual add Action of CommentsController was invoked (and thus the add View of comments), I got a blackhole error of type 'auth', which I could not explain so I caught it with this way - this might even be related to my problems.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why this should be a problem (and I've used this method). Are you caching the element? Is the comments form accidentally rendered inside another form? Can you post the HTML output of the element somewhere?

Comment: The element was indeed being cached which could have been the reason, but now I removed all the caching and still it does not work (I also deleted the actual cache files). No, the comments form is not rendered inside another form. See the edit for the HTML output.

Comment: Okay, I'll need to see the controller code. Also, put `debug($this->Form->request->params)` in the element *and* in the view and let's see the output. My guess is that the problem lies in how you're re-rendering the element, which I don't fully understand from your question (the controller code should clear this up).

Comment: Alright, I've uploaded what you want. See my edit. The debug output does not really show anything useful if you ask me... Note that by re-rendering the element after submitting the form with invalid data, the Debugger::log() line gets executed twice since it is in both the element and the add View. Also see my explanations about the settings regarding the Security component. Thanks man!

Comment: How odd! You're missing the `_Token` key in your params which is required to generate the secure fields. It's even missing in the view, which means it's maybe a problem with the session. If you debug `$this->request->params` in the controller you should see the token in there. If you don't then it's not getting set. If you're available, we should chat to track down the problem instead of do it in the comments.

Comment: Alright, thanks so far. I will create a chat room and try to invite you whenever we happen to be online at the same time. EDIT, don't know how to explicitly invite, but here's the URL: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15835/cakephp-2-1-using-csrf-protection-on-elements

Comment: Forget the chat - adding the Security component to the PostsController solved the problem. Now, the add_comments Form has the token, and the add.ctp Form also has a Token given the input was not valid. Weirdly, when I remove the Security component from the PostsController (only one in the CommentsController), both forms, i.e. the element AND the view, do not have a Token. So I don't really grasp what happens between those two stages, but anyway, it works (it really does, threw Errors when Token was manipulated). Thanks for your help, nonetheless!

Comment: Whoa, duh. Not sure how I missed that, it's in the first sentence of your question. I guess I just assumed you already had the SecurityComponent enabled in it. At any rate, glad you figured it out!